# Gradient descent to solve regressions with large features

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gradient-descent

We know that the closed-form solution for linear regression is $\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$.
$X$ is a $N\times M$ matrix, where N is the number of observations and M is the number of features.

However, in the case when we have more features than observations, $M>N$, $X'X$ is not longer invertible since the $M\times M$ matrix of $X'X$ is not full rank. As a result, we can no longer use the closed form solution.

Would it be possible (and reasonable) then to use the gradient descent approach to solve for $\beta$? 
It is commonly mentioned that gradient descent is preferred to using the closed-form solution since it doesn't require inverting the $X'X$ matrix which can be time intensive, especially for large $M$.

I was curious if gradient descent can also always guarantee a solution when the closed-form solution can't.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore–Penrose_inverse), too.

Comment: gradient descent *with weight decay* can guarantee a unique solution because its equivalent to ridge regression

Answer (score 0):

> It is commonly mentioned that gradient descent is preferred to using the closed-form solution since it doesn't require inverting the X'X matrix which can be time intensive, especially for large M

I am under the impression that inversion of the hat matrix *is not* how statistical packages fit linear models.  Rather, [the QR factorization](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Elarget/math496/qr.html) is employed.

> Would it be possible (and reasonable) then to use the gradient descent approach to solve for β?

Possible?  I believe so.  The only condition here is that the minimum is not unique, and so the answer would depend on where you start.

Comment: can you please explain why the minimum would not be unique in this instance?

Comment: @vpy Because $X$ has $N<M$  then the dimension of the kernel of $X$ is greater than 0.  This means I can write $y = X (\beta - \beta^*)$ for $\beta^*$ in the kernel of $X$.  Hence, the solution to the equation $y=X\beta$ is not unique.